# xcode size class vs actual iphone resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Something still not very clear. We know for example iphone 5s has a  resolution of 320 x 568 points.
If on xocde, storyboard I use “wAny hAny” size class and place a VIEW(UIView) sized 500h x 500w and constrain it to the top, left, right and bottom of super view.
In there I can fit 100 50x50 points images, like 10 images per row. 
Now if I run this app on the iphone 5 simulator I am not able to see 10 images in a row since the width is only 320?
Maybe iOS will resize the images so they can hit? What if I don’t want those images to be resized?
Can someone please help me with this or guide me to a document that explain this?

Comment: "iphone 5s has a resolution of 320 x 568 " No, that is a size, not a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The superview will be resized, when the app runs, to fit the screen. So, since you have pinned the view to the top, left, right, and bottom of the superview, it will be resized as well.

It is up to you to take all this resizing into account when you design your interface and add your constraints. The whole *point* of constraints is to allow you to design in the face of all this resizing.

Thus, as for your 10 images, they will certainly not fit at fixed width 50, 10 to a row, when the app actually runs, because (as I just said) the superview is going to be resized. It is up to you to design the interface and the constraints so that they *will* fit.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. so since the max size view I can have in “wAny hAny” size class is 600 x 600, and constrain it to top, left, right, and bottom, then if I run it in iphone5, this will be resized to 320x568 and if I run it on iphone 4s, then will be resized to 320x480? so if my requirement is to have those 100 images (10 per row of 10 rows), then in order for example to fit 100 images in iphone 5, I need each image to be 32x56 points? now if I want to run this on iphone 4, can the OS resize them to 32x48 points? Or do I need to create a size class for each iphone?

Comment: (1) This has nothing to do with size classes. (2) "if I run it in iphone5, this will be resized to 320x568 and if I run it on iphone 4s, then will be resized to 320x480?" Correct. (3) "now if I want to run this on iphone 4, can the OS resize them to 32x48 points" It can do whatever you tell it to do. You tell it using constraints, or code, or both.

Comment: @borna Just to give an example, my "99 Bottles" app has 99 bottle images displayed in 11 rows of 9 each. Those images fit perfectly on any size iPhone screen - 4s, 5, 6, or 6 Plus. They form a perfect grid that fills the screen. Why? Because my code configures them so that they do!

Comment: So what is the best practice? I want to display 100 images (10 per row) and I want this app to be supported on iphone 4 and above. How many different image sizes I need to create?

Comment: Thank Matt, on your 99 bottles app, when you created the image originally in photoshop or whatever app, what size images you created? for example did you created multiple size of the same image such that in your code you say if 4 then use iphon4image.png else if 5 use iphone5image.png and so on?

Comment: "when you created the image originally in photoshop or whatever app, what size images you created" Big. When the app runs, I draw them into the actual size needed for that size of screen.